# Proper way to do a PATCH request

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, http-method

Im using ASP.Net Core 2. I need to update a user in a Azure AD with Microsofts Graph API. The API documentation states that i should send the properties of the user in the body and specify the user in the URL like so:

> https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version

The documentation states that it should be a PATCH request. But HTTPRequestMessage does not accept PATCH as a HttpMethod. What is the proper way to make a PATCH request with asp.net core 2?

When i google i find that all answers suggests using JsonPatch, but that is a format that is not supported by Microsoft Graph API.

This is what i have so far....

```
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var requestUri = $"{_azureAdOptions.GraphInstance}/{_azureAdOptions.GraphVersion}/{_azureAdOptions.Domain}/users/me";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod., requestUri);

        var accessToken = await _authenticationHelper.GetAccessTokenAsync();
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the nature of `Http`, and the craziness of developers, you can create your own http server with custom methods. The class [HttpMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmethod.httpmethod(v=vs.118).aspx) was created with this in mind  allowing you to specify the method as string:

```
var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH"); // Patch
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method , requestUri); // Use patch
```

Note: The new version of [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.patchasync?view=netcore-2.1&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7.2) comes with `Patch` method by default.

Comment: Lovely! Now this developer is about to go crazy!